# What happens to data disks when resizing an Azure VM?

Tags: azure

I have an Azure VM instance of `Standard A2` size that I wish to resize to `Standard A1` since it's rather underutilized. The problem is that I have four data disks attached, but the `Standard A1` size supports a maximum of two.

What will happen if I attempt to resize the instance?

---

**Edit:** If it allows me to resize the VM whilst retaining the attached disks, can I expect them to stick around or would it leave the VM in an unsuppored state where the disks could be lost at any time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to resize to a lower instance in this case. Azure will return an error like the one below either using portal ou powershell:

> Too many data disks specified for virtual machine DEMOVM01. The
>   maximum number of data disks currently permitted is 2. The current
>   number of data disks is 3. The operation is attempting to add 1
>   additional data disks.

Basically to scale down you'd have to manually detach data disks before resizing. Detaching a disk won't delete it tho.