# After resizing Azure Linux VM, data in the attached datadisk is lost. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, hard-drive

Here is the general information :

- I created and attached standard SSD datadisk on the creation of the ubuntu VM.
- Aplication files were on the datadisk.
- I mounted datadisk following [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/tr-tr/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal) except one difference : mounting disk on the $HOME/datadrive/ instead of /datadrive.

Then :

- I resized Azure Linux VM size from B1s (1GB RAM) to B1ms (2GB RAM).
- Server is restarted as expected.
- After connecting via shh and listing content of the ~/datadrive, I realized that all the data is lost.

Is it because of the mounting under the home directory?

What should I do to not experience data lost in the disk again?

[This](https://serverfault.com/q/749379/618278) is not anwering my question.

Edit :

Here is the content of /etc/fstab :

```
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
UUID=bdf328db-9606-49ba-8e44-5e1299ae56f0   /    ext4   defaults,discard0 0
UUID=54D1-0F3A  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults,discard    0 0


UUID=b08e9d03-eec1-4517-b09c-b349e7791923   /datadrive   xfs   defaults,nofail   1 
/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig   0   2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add your `/etc/fstab` and the relevant logs from `/var/log`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue month ago but forgot the posting about it. Sorry for inconvenience who faces the same problem.

I couldn't understand the very details, but he issue was about mounting. I remounted the disk, and recovered the data.